# Dynamic table with bootstrap

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to do dynamic table with bootstrap but I can't deduce why it's not working. There's a HTML part:

```
    <div class="container">
        <button onclick="CreateTable()">Extend</button>          
        <table class="table">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Employee Id</th>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Country</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>John Doe</td>
                    <td>Country1</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>2</td>
                    <td>Mary Moe</td>
                    <td>Country2</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>3</td>
                    <td>Jack Dooley</td>
                    <td>Country3</td>
                </tr>
                <p id="id_tabela"></p>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
```

and there's javascript:

```
        function CreateTable() {
            var employee = new Array();
            employee.push([4, "Billie Jean", "Country4"]);
            employee.push([5, "Harish Kumar", "Country5"]);
            employee.push([6, "Pankaj Mohan", "Country6"]);
            employee.push([7, "Nitin Srivastav", "Country7"]);
            employee.push([8, "Ramchandra Verma", "Country8"]);

            var tablecontents = "";
            for (var i = 0; i < employee.length; i++) {
                tablecontents += "<tr>";
                for (var j = 0; j < employee[i].length; j++) {
                    tablecontents += "<td>" + employee[i][j] + "</td>";
                }
                tablecontents += "</tr>";
            }
            document.getElementById("id_tabela").innerHTML = tablecontents;
        }
```

So I want to extend the table and I can't figure out why it's not working.

Comment: employee.push({4, "Billie Jean", "Country4"}); update to curly braces.

Answer (score 1):

You are loading the data *inside* the paragraph, which is not what you want to do. Also the paragraph shouldn't be there. You can add an `id` to `tbody` and then just extend its `innerHTML` like so: https://jsfiddle.net/14pt76wp/.

Why are you using native functions? bootstrap has jQuery included. You could do something like:

```
$('table tbody').append(tablecontents);
```

Another trick:

1. Iterate over the array and do
    `employee[i] = '<td>' + employee[i].join('</td><td>') + '</td>';`
2. `tablecontents = '<tr>' + employee.join('</tr><tr>') + '</tr>';`